# shortest way to texting in Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

For me, it used to be a lock screen widget where I swiped right and could start texting my contacts. I thinks this is now gone for some reason. So what's the fastest way to get to texting from lock screen in this new stupid lollipop version?

Answer (score 1):

Using absolutely stock, as-installed-by-default stuff, the fastest way would be:

- Swipe to unlock
- Tap home button
- Tap Messenger or Hangouts (which you have put as an icon on your home screen)
- Tap new message.

Possible ways to reduce the number of steps:

- Third-party SMS apps which provide homescreen widgets that take you straight into composing
- Third-party lock screen replacements
- Alternative ROMs with different lock screen arrangements (e.g. some Cyanogenmod versions let you define different apps to be launched depending on the direction of your unlock swipe)

Comment: So no news of google reintroducing right-swipe from lockscreen to get to texting? :(